# How to download txt file from the server system to client?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="dlde" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class dlde : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    var fileName = @"D:\Error.txt";
    var r = context.Response;
    r.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    r.ContentType = "text/plain";
    r.WriteFile(context.Server.MapPath(fileName));
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I want to download the .txt file from the server system from the specified directory...i tried with this code,but i am getting error,invalid virtual path..How to get the file ,from the server system ..please help me...

Comment: Show the exact exception and on what line it occurs. Does the file exist?

Comment: '@D:\Error.txt' is not a valid virtual path.

Comment: I asked a few more questions than just that one in my comment, but anyway, then don't `Server.MapPath()` it, because it is already an absolute path.

Comment: it is directory path file name D drive

Answer (score 0):

try this by using `"WebClient "`

```
     string remoteUri = "http://Yoursite.com/file.txt";
     string fileName = @"D:\";
      WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
      myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);
```

Learning from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for namespace

Answer (score 0):

```
 string fName = @"D:\Error.txt";

 System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(fName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
 byte[] btFile = new byte[fs.Length];
 fs.Read(btFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
 fs.Close();

 context.Response.Clear();
 context.Response.ClearHeaders();
 context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; 
           filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fname, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
 context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";  
 context.Response.BinaryWrite(btFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string fName = @hdfRuta.Value; //Ruta donde se encuentra el archivo txt Ejm: c:\log\log21082018.txt

        System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(fName, 
        System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        byte[] btFile = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(btFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + hdfNombreArchivo.Value); //hdfNombreArchivo: Nombre del archivo .txt a generarse Ejm: Log_21_08_2018.txt
        EnableViewState = false;
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";  
        Response.BinaryWrite(btFile);
        Response.End();


    protected void btnBajarLog_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        ScriptManager newScriptManager = 
       (ScriptManager)Page.FindControl("scmRegistroMasivoEvento");
        newScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(btn);
    }
```

Comment: Consider adding some text to your answer as to why your answer works.